# Change Dropout rate during training in tensorflow - is it possible?

Tags: tensorflow, machine-learning, neural-network

i thought that it could be sometimes a good idea to change the dropout rate during the training of a neural network (in particular: a general adversarial network), starting with high dropout rates and linearilly decreasing the dropout rate to zero.
Do you think this could make sense and if yes, is there any possibility to realize this in tensorflow?

Comment: By the way, [here](https://ieeexplore.ieee.org/document/7078567) is a paper on this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can pass a placeholder to `keep_prob` argument of [tf.nn.dropout](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/nn/dropout) in order to be able to feed arbitrary dropout rates during runtime:

```
# array of ones
data=np.ones((3,4), dtype=np.float32)

keep_prob = tf.placeholder(tf.float32)
drop = tf.nn.dropout(data, keep_prob=keep_prob)

sess = tf. InteractiveSession()

print(sess.run(drop, feed_dict={keep_prob: 0.5}))
# >>> [[0. 2. 0. 2.]
#      [0. 2. 0. 0.]
#      [2. 2. 2. 2.]]

print(sess.run(drop, feed_dict={keep_prob: 1.0}))
# >>> [[1. 1. 1. 1.]
#      [1. 1. 1. 1.]
#      [1. 1. 1. 1.]]
```

As for whether this makes sense or not, the best way to verify it is to  run sets of experiments with static and varying dropout rates, then compare the results.